# First time using html and css, trying to make it fit in mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile

This is my first attempt at using html and css. I know there’s many mistakes in the code, but if someone could point me in a direction to get it viewable in mobile, I’d be very appreciative.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Change styles based on the device you are using

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* default styles here for older browsers. 
       I tend to go for a 600px - 960px width max but using percentages
    */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
        /* styles for browsers larger than 960px; */
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
        /* styles for browsers larger than 1440px; */
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
        /* for sumo sized (mac) screens */
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
       /* styles for mobile browsers smaller than 480px; (iPhone) */
    }
    @media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
       /* default iPad screens */
    }
    /* different techniques for iPad screening */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
      /* For portrait layouts only */
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
      /* For landscape layouts only */
    }
</style>
```